# Some icons missing in Nautilus

Tags: unity, nautilus, icons

I've noticed that many icons are missing in my folder view, but have no idea when or how this happened. Here's the screenshot:

[image: missing icons]

The icons that are missing are those from the sidebar and navigation bar, they are shown as a red missing sign on black background.

Any ideas how this happened and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you using any themes?  If yes, which one?

Comment: Do you mean icon themes? Yes, I do use  Faenza icon theme, but this problem remains even if I change the theme to any other. I've tried changing the icon theme to Humanity, Gnome, Oxygen, even Ubuntu's default themes, and the problem still remained. Also, I've been using Faenza for a couple of years, and this problem never existed until now.

Comment: After changing the icon theme, did you log out and log back in again?

Comment: I don't think I did. When using Ubuntu Tweak to change the icon theme, it gets applied right away, so I thought I didn't need to log out. I'll try that now and let you know if it helped.

Comment: I'm sorry, logging out didn't help. Maybe it would help if someone without this problem showed me a list of all the icon themes installed, so I see what theme I'm missing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Re-installing the `gnome-icon-theme-symbolic` package did the trick. Thanks to the hint from this thread: http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-946138-start-0.html

From `apt-cache show gnome-icon-theme-symbolic`:

```
Description-en: GNOME desktop icon theme (symbolic icons)
 This package contains a set of icons used by the GNOME desktop.
 The icons are used in the panel menu, and in nautilus and other
 applications, to represent the different applications, files,
 directories, and devices.
```

Comment: Hi, do you now see this listed as a separate icon theme in `/usr/share/icons`? In other words, where does the `gnome-icon-theme-symbolic` package install to?

Comment: No, it doesn't exist under that name in `/usr/share/icons`. However, it is installed in the `/usr/share/icons/gnome` folder, I think it shares the same installation folder with the other Gnome icon packs, such as `gnome-icon-theme`, `gnome-icon-theme-full`, `gnome-icon-theme-extras` etc.

Comment: This worked for me as well. Thanks!
`sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-icon-theme-symbolic`